# How do I get a set of objects belonging to another set of objects in Rails 4 ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

If I have two models, say, an user Model and a Company model like those defined below. How do I get all of the companies of a set of users?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

users = User.where(:state => "Florida")
```

From this, I need a variable that holds all of the companies belonging to those users

```
companies = users.?
```

Do I need to loop through each of the users and add them to an array? I'm guessing there is a better way to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
Company.includes(:users).where(users: { state: 'Florida' })
```

BUT Taking into account [http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ recommendations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations)

It will be more correct to do

```
Company.joins(:users).where(users: { state: 'Florida'})
```

This does `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`